# json parsing in android working with kimono api

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am working with a parsing json and fetching my json data from kimono.I am fetching json from following url:
 http://www.brankart.com/test/tra.json
My mainactivity goes as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://www.brankart.com/test/tra.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String lnk = "href";
private static final String d1 = "text";
private static final String dt = "property2";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(lnk, name);
            in.putExtra(dt, cost);
            in.putExtra(d1, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONObject nsb = jsonObj.getJSONObject("results");                    

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = nsb.getJSONArray("collection1");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject p1 = c.getJSONObject("property1");

                    String link = p1.getString(lnk);
                    String descp = p1.getString(d1);
                    String detail = p1.getString(dt);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(lnk, link);
                    contact.put(d1, descp);
                    contact.put(dt, detail);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { d1, dt,
                        lnk }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

I am still not able to fetch my json in listview.Please help

Comment: What happens when you try? I tried to run your code and it fails because of the parsing of the `JSON` file from the server. Post your stacktrace in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try change doInBackground like below

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONObject nsb = jsonObj.getJSONObject("results");                    

            // Getting JSON Array node
            contacts = nsb.getJSONArray("collection1");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject p1 = c.getJSONObject("property1");

                String link = p1.getString(lnk);
                String descp = p1.getString(d1);
                //change here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                String detail = c.getString(dt);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(lnk, link);
                contact.put(d1, descp);
                contact.put(dt, detail);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
}
```